# How to import react libraries into pure jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, jsx

I'm following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-blogging-app-using-react-user-sign-in--cms-28568) tutorial.

It uses JSX files to contain the relevant react code for each component of the system so Home, Index etc along with a corresponding HTML file.

I'm used to using pure React where I can import libraries by using the `import` keyword.

However in JSX it seems I have to declare the libraries differently by importing them into the HTML via script sources.

How would I go about importing [this](https://github.com/mkhstar/suneditor-react/blob/master/README.md) text editor library which is for ReactJS when it expects the typical import call.

I've tried following the current architecture from the tutorial by declaring it differently in the JSX file as `var SunEditor = 'suneditor-react';`

This does not work, I've had to instead import the pure Javascript version of the library which is the first one [here](http://suneditor.com/sample/html/getting-started.html). As by using the pure JS version I can simply import via script references in the corresponding HTML file that matches the given JSX file.
i.e. `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suneditor@latest/dist/suneditor.min.js"></script>`

Comment: The README you linked has a [Getting Started](https://github.com/mkhstar/suneditor-react/blob/master/README.md#getting-started) section that shows how to import and use the `SunEditor`: `import SunEditor from 'suneditor-react';` and `import 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css'; // Import Sun Editor's CSS File`. That tutorial seems terribly dated, try following https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html project setup & config.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've created many projects via create-react-app but I already have this project built but its using JSX as a means to self-contain the ReactJS code rather than using JS files.Here is an example of the Main.JSX file. [Define the required react-router variables to create links in the main.jsx file.] `var Router = window.ReactRouter.Router; var Route = window.ReactRouter.Route; var hashHistory = window.ReactRouter.hashHistory; var Link = window.ReactRouter.Link; class AddPost extends React.Component {


  
    constructor(props) {} ... etc`